# how to remove leading extra space for each row when pandata datafarme is converted to_string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I am trying to convert to string using newdf= old_df.to_string(index=False). After this step automatically spaces are being added to the first
2 row's. Any suggessions how to remove that?

old_df:

```
column_name
row1
row2
row3
```

newdf:

```
    row1
    row2
row3
```

If I do newdf=newdf.lstrip(' ') then the space at first row is removed but space at 2nd row remains as it is

newdf:

```
row1
    row2
row3
```

Comment: Your formatting makes the question is unclear, please double check, and ideally provide DataFrame constructors (or dictionaries)

Comment: `to_string` creates a string representation of the whole dataframe (one big string with many line breaks), I'm almost sure this is not what you really want. Maybe you can tell us what your final goal is.

Comment: `newdf.str.strip()`

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `.toString(index=False)` you will always have that problem. So if you want to fix the spacing issue just use `.toString()`.

Like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {'c1': [2, 3, 4], 'c2': [5, 6, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
newdf= df.to_string()
print(newdf)
```

Comment: I am trying to get a  string out of a DataFrame, which can then be replaced with another string in a text document. I am using this text document as an email body and sending email. But after doing df.to_string() either with or without index=False I am getting extra spaces which are reflecting in my email. That makes the email format look bad.

Comment: with open('mail_body.txt', 'r') as file:
     data = file.read().replace('Record', newdf)
     msg = EmailMessage()
     msg.set_content(data)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As previouslyy stated above, if you're only trtying to get a spcific value from the df, the function to_string() might not be the right one for you.
As it might be better to concatenatethe values from the df into a string and format it as you like.